# How to use tab in a batch executable to complete a line?

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

I am writing a launcher script for a .jar file because for some reason many of my users have issues run a .jar on double click even with the right jre and javaw.exe as their default software opener. The jar will only open with `java -jar foobar.jar`. So I'm writing a script to do this but the jar name changes every time there's an update. It'll be `java -jar foobar3.0.jar` vs `java -jar foobar4.0.jar`. Is there a way to write a script that'll just do something like `java -jar foobar TAB`, so that it just auto completes the rest of the name because that's the only file with that name in the folder?

Comment: A wildcard perhaps ?

Comment: `for %%a in (foobar*.jar) do java -jar %%a`

Comment: It's pretty strange that double-clicking the .jar file doesn't work.  I suspect the users have an older version of Java associated with the .jar extension.  Consider distributing your .jar using Java Web Start, so you can guarantee that users are running with an adequate version of Java.  (Plus, you can provide a nice icon for the double-clickable shortcut.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `java -jar foobar*.jar`. The `*` is a standard regular expression wildcard, and means any string; in this context, it means any string that will make a valid path. Note that this means that if there is any other jar file starting with foobar, then which one it chooses is implementation dependent, i.e. you can't predict it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching for "tab"/autocomplete, what you probably need to be looking at is how to match a file name.

Using an `*` should solve your problems, so the line would be something like `java -jar foobar*.jar`. Definitely works under Linux, should work under Windows as well. (You didn't specify the operating system).

Now this can be problematic if there are multiple files that match that pattern. If you are sure that there is only one in the folder than it's fine.

Another suggestion is to not change the name of the jar for every release - put them in zip files that have the version name and a README or whatever and keep the base jar name the same - this way the user just drops the new version in the existing folder and overwrites it, no need for changing paths.